# Pure virtual input output operator overloading

Tags: c++, oop, io

School assignment:
I recieved a source code that im not allowed to change.
I must implement the next things:
Interfaces made from pure virtuals "IPrintable" and "IComparable"
the relevant one is IPrintable
which contains overloads for IO operators.
Date class that implements those two.
and another template class that is irrelevant to this question

My current problem is im not sure how to do the overloading while its pure, since the io operators are also friends and not direct. 
It does not have to be a template, however i cant think of another way to get easy access to the derivative functions and privates.
This is the IO header:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef  IPrintable_h
#define IPrintable_h
template<typename T>

class IPrintable {
    virtual friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const T&) = 0;
    virtual friend istream& operator>>(istream&, T&) = 0;
};
#endif // ! IPrintable_h
```

the relevant parts of the derivative class header:

```
#include "IComparable.h"
#include "IPrintable.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
.
.
class Date : public IPrintable<Date>, IComparable<Date> {
.
.
.
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Date&);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream&, Date&);
```

So far VS didnt say there are errors, however im not sure which is why im asking here.
if there arent any, then the problem is probably in the way i try implementing it in Date.cpp:

```
ostream& std::operator<<(ostream& stream, const Date& requested){
```

Unchangable source code part:

```
void testDate() {
    Date independence(14, 5, 1948);
    Date otherDate = independence;

    cout << "Independence:" << independence << ", Other: " << otherDate << endl;
    otherDate.setMonth(2);
    cout << "Other date: " << otherDate << endl;
    otherDate.setDay(29);
    cout << "Other date: " << otherDate << endl;
    otherDate.setYear(1947);
    cout << "Other date: " << otherDate << endl;

    otherDate = Date(24, 1, 1959);
    cout << "Other date: " << otherDate << endl;

    cout << "Comparing using polymorphism" << endl;
    IComparable<Date> *indP = dynamic_cast <IComparable<Date> *> (&independence);
    cout << "Is independence <= otherDate ? " << (*indP <= otherDate) << endl;

    IComparable<Date> *otherP = dynamic_cast <IComparable<Date> *> (&otherDate);
    cout << "Is other date <= independence ? " << (*otherP <= independence) << endl;

}

void testDateInput() {
    Date otherDate(1, 1, 1);
    do {
        cin >> otherDate;
        cout << otherDate << endl;
    } while (otherDate != Date(1, 1, 1));
}
```

Edited for the sake of making the assignment more clear

Adding part of the requested source code and full headers

Comment: *"Basically i need to make a template pure virtual input/output operator overloading header"* Seems again a wrong assignment :-/

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to use `template` and `pure virtual` at once here? As for friend/static functions in general, consider an implementation like `{ return requested.write(stream);}` if `IPrintable::write` is a virtual method.

Comment: To be fair, looking at it, i just tossed it with the other class into being a template. Printable indeed doesnt have to be a template. However it must be a pure virtual. will edit the original post

Comment: using the namespace std is good, but `using namspace std;` is not :P. And it is never irrelevant when it is inside a header. If you know it is bad, why do you do it?

Comment: can you try to be more clear on what the requirements of the assignment are on the one hand and what you think needs to be done to meet them on the other hand? Somewhere something went a bit wrong, but it is not clear where

Comment: I will expand on the actual assignment. The irrelevant part has been dealt with in another question, has no connection to _IPrintable_

Comment: sorry, i have to ask again, which is the code that you cannot modify and which is the code you wrote?

Comment: All of the code posted is modifiable.

Comment: So what can't you change and what are the requirements of `IPrintable`?

Comment: As it is currently written, `IPrintable` is completely pointless.

Comment: I cant change the main source code which just uses operators that had to be overloaded by Printable and Comparable. Printable needs to have pure virtual overloads for << and >>

Comment: @Merkava At least post the relevant parts. Right now the only thing we know is that there is *a source code* you can't change. What is it?

Comment: OK, now you've added it ... where's `IPrintable` in the given code?

Comment: BTW "i know `using namespace std;` is bad practice, but for this school project its irrelevant." then just delete it.

Comment: IPrintable is a header file with PURE VIRTUAL functions that have to be implemented in the Date class. Thats the whole thing. I need to implement the overloads to << and >>

Comment: Even if virtual friends were allowed, it would be really weird. The code you've given doesn't use `IPrintable`. You can use overload the stream operators without `IPrintable`

Comment: I know i can, but the assignment demands it to go through IPrintable. I know this is not the way people code in jobs, most of those assignments in this school arent. However right now, this is the situation. I need to make it work with IPrintable

Comment: You could have separate functions `virtual void toStream(std::ostream &) = 0;` and call those from the stream operators `friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const T &);`

Comment: I know, trust me. Il try doing it with separate functions, just got a message from a classmate that did that as well since its the only thing he could think of.